# How to validate a copy of the pydantic model created with `model_copy`?

Tags: python, pydantic

Consider the following code

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, ValidationError


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(
        frozen=True,
        extra='forbid',
        strict=True,
    )

    a: int


# will fail with a ValidationError
try:
    MyModel(a="a")
except ValidationError:
    print("The right exception was thrown")

# works but not as I would expect
m = MyModel(a=1)
assert m.a == 1
m_copy = m.model_copy(update={"a": "a-string"})
assert m_copy.a == "a-string"

# works
m_copy.model_validate(m_copy, strict=True)
print("model is valid ... but why?")
```

If you run the code, the output would be:

```
The right exception was thrown
model is valid ... but why?
```

The question is, how can I validate a model after creating a copy of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation for [`model_copy`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.BaseModel.model_copy), "note: the data is not validated before creating the new model. You should trust this data."

Comment: As for `model_validate` with `strict=True` not raising a `ValidationError`, that should be an error, please consider filing an issue at the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/).

Comment: In any case, you should only pass known validated data to the `update` argument, e.g. `MyModel.model_copy(update=dict(MyModel(a=1)))`.